# Does the Logitech QuickCam Pro 9000 (USB 2.0) work on Mac OS X?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, logitech-webcam

Does the **Logitech QuickCam Pro 9000 (USB 2.0)** work on Mac OS X 10.6? Or do I really have to get the more expensive Mac-edition called **Logitech QuickCam Vision Pro MAC (USB 2.0)**?

Generally speaking I'm looking for a new USB webcam for Skype. Here are my requirements:

- high-quality
- USB 2.0 / driverless (don't want to depend on a vendor's low-quality driver/software)
- Mac OS X 10.6 compatible (incl **64-bit** Snow Leopard kernel)

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick google search reveals [this page](http://www.junyor.net/2009/08/29/snow-leopard-logitech-quickcam-pro-9000/) which says that while it does not work on Leopard, it does work on Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 2):

USB Webcams by default will use Apple's built in USB Webcam driver (available 10.4.9+), so without a complete driver from Logitech a lot of the extra features are not available. If this doesn't bother you (since you don't want to do depend on a vendor's drivers) then you'll be just fine. There are however several programs that will allow you to change the white balance, colour and other bits from [Ecamm](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/iglasses/).

So yes, both cameras will work with Snow Leopard just fine, and Apple's extension if it's not already 64-bit will be soon.